# До какого уровня\версии PyQt5 поддерживает html\css в объекте QLabel() ? И можно ли настраивать?

Tags: html, css, pyqt5

Пример:
***some_python_file.py :***

```
with open("data.html", "r", encoding = "UTF-8") as data_file:
    data_text = data_file.read()
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
Q_text = QLabel()
Q_text.setText(data_text)
Q_text.show()
sys.exit(app._exec())
```

***data.html :***

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
    h1 {color: black;}
    rq_type {color:black; font: bold 12px}
    rq_hotkey {
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color:black;
        color: black;
        background-color: grey;
        font: bold 12px;
        }
    p, li {font:12px;}


</style>
<h1> Основы </h1>
<h2> Необходимые знания </h2>
<h3>Объекты</h3>
<p>Приложенние графический визуализатор строит графики с помощью динамических объектов.</p>
<h3>Динамические объекты :</h3>
<ul>
    <li> <rq_type>Действие</rq_type> - предствляет собой объект для базовых действий ( + , - , / , * ).
        <br/>
        Можно создать с помощью клавишы <rq_hotkey>CapsLock</rq_hotkey>
    </li>
    <li> <rq_type>Число</rq_type> - представляет собой объект для чисел
        <br/>
        Можно создать с помощью клавишы <rq_hotkey>Tab</rq_hotkey>
    </li>
    <li> <rq_type>Дополнение</rq_type> - представляет собой составной объект для дополнений
        <br/>
        Можно создать с помощью кнопки <em>Добавить дополнение</em>
        <br/>
        Выбор дополнения осуществляется в соответсвенном меню
    </li>
    <li> <rq_type>Переменная</rq_type> - представляет собой динамически изменяющееся значение
        <br/>
        Можно создать если ввести в объект <rq_type>Число</rq_type> знак "x"
    </li>
</ul>
<h3>Ошибки и их обработка</h3>
<ol>
    <li>Действие идет после действия</li>
    <li>Число идёт после числа</li>
    <li>До\После Дополнения идет Число</li>
</ol>

<hr/>
<code>Нажми на меня </code>
```

На моменте с установкой стиля для тега `<rq_hotkey>` (data.html > style > rq_hotkey)
Отказался работать атрибут или стиль (не знаю как это зовется css, 5 минут назад начал изучать) border.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, до какой границы работают такие стили и как это можно настраивать.
Заранее спасибо!